# Find specific link text with bs4

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website and find all the headings of a feed. I am having trouble just getting the text of the `a` tag that I need. Here is an example of the html.

```
<td class="m" id="b1"><a href="/QSYcfT" id="c1" target="_blank" onClick="vPI('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BFNH-6K10Ic', 'QSYcfT', this.id); this.blur(); return false;">TF4 - Oreos</a> <a href="#" onClick="return lkP('1', 'QSYcfT');" id="x1"><font class="bp">(0)</font></a>
<td class="m" id="b2"><a href="/zXHNvp" id="c2" target="_blank" onClick="vPI('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vjcGwZGBYI', 'zXHNvp', this.id); this.blur(); return false;">Awesome Game Boy Facts</a> <a href="#" onClick="return lkP('2', 'zXHNvp');" id="x2"><font class="bp">(0)</font></a>
```

I am trying to get the text for every `a` tag with a id of `c` and print each on a new line.

My output should look like this.

```
TF4 - Oreos
Awesome Game Boy Facts
```

So far I have tried.

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
links = soup.find_all('a',{'id' : 'c'})
for link in links:
    print link.text
```

But it doesn't find or print anything?

Comment: I would accept all these working answers and responses if I could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [pass a regular expression](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments) in place of an attribute value:

```
links = soup.find_all('a', {'id': re.compile('^c\d+')})
```

`^` means the beginning of a string, `\d+` matches one or more digits.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> html = """
... <tr>
...     <td class="m" id="b1"><a href="/QSYcfT" id="c1" target="_blank" onClick="vPI('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BFNH-6K10Ic', 'QSYcfT', this.id); this.blur(); return false;">TF4 - Oreos</a> <a href="#" onClick="return lkP('1', 'QSYcfT');" id="x1"><font class="bp">(0)</font></a></td>
...     <td class="m" id="b2"><a href="/zXHNvp" id="c2" target="_blank" onClick="vPI('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vjcGwZGBYI', 'zXHNvp', this.id); this.blur(); return false;">Awesome Game Boy Facts</a> <a href="#" onClick="return lkP('2', 'zXHNvp');" id="x2"><font class="bp">(0)</font></a></td>
... </tr>
... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> links = soup.find_all('a', {'id': re.compile('^c\d+')})
>>> for link in links:
...     print link.text
... 
TF4 - Oreos
Awesome Game Boy Facts
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no `a` tag with the attribute `c`, but `c1` and `c2`.

```
links = soup.find_all('a',{'id' : 'c1'})
```

If you want to find all `a` with attribute that starts with `c`, you need to pass regular expression:

```
import re

links = soup.findAll('a', {'id': re.compile('^c')})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a [regular expression](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) object inside the call to [`find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all)

```
import re
import bs4

html = '''
<td class="m" id="b1"><a href="/QSYcfT" id="c1" target="_blank" onClick="vPI('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BFNH-6K10Ic', 'QSYcfT', this.id); this.blur(); return false;">TF4 - Oreos</a> <a href="#" onClick="return lkP('1', 'QSYcfT');" id="x1"><font class="bp">(0)</font></a>
<td class="m" id="b2"><a href="/zXHNvp" id="c2" target="_blank" onClick="vPI('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vjcGwZGBYI', 'zXHNvp', this.id); this.blur(); return false;">Awesome Game Boy Facts</a> <a href="#" onClick="return lkP('2', 'zXHNvp');" id="x2"><font class="bp">(0)</font></a>
'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
for links in soup.find_all('a', {'id' : re.compile('^c') }):
    print ''.join(links.find_all(text=True))
```

Output

```
TF4 - Oreos
Awesome Game Boy Facts
```