# Python Web scraping: Finding specific link

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to isolate a specific link for images from a web page but can't quite get there. The HTML looks something like:

```
<head>
   <img alt="Generic title" src="https://genericURL/photo/picture.jpg/"> 
   <img src="https://genericurl/.../">
   <img src="https://genericurl/.../">
   ....
```

I am able to return many links but the link I specifically want is the top one shown, it is the only link containing `/photo/picture.jpg`.
I have tried using the answer from [Find specific link text with bs4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762464/find-specific-link-text-with-bs4) and other variations but haven't figured it out yet. Is anyone able to take a look please?

My code:

```
links = soup.findAll('img', {'src': re.compile('^http://image\d+')})
for link in links:
     print(link.text)
```

EDIT: Using the suggestions I realised that the link format was changing based on the filter I was using, e.g.: when I was printing the entire web page I saw the link as `http://image...`. However when I was using `findAll('img', {'src' ...` the link was outputting as `https://img` so I was trying to re.compile the wrong things.

Comment: Why not `re.compile("photo/picture.jpg")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
links = soup.findAll('img', {'src': re.compile('^http://image\d+')})
for link in links:
    if re.search('photo\/pictures\.jpg', link.get('href', ''), re.IGNORECASE):
        link_i_want = link.get('href')
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

```
soup.find_all("img", alt="Generic title")
```

you should use `alt` as filter.